# How to Print corresponding row for a maximum value of last column?

Tags: awk

I am trying to print the entire row for a max value of last column based on second last column -

input file : file1.txt

```
2019-01-16 08:00:00.0   test1   28848859233
2019-01-16 08:00:00.0   test2   902006478
2019-01-16 08:00:00.0   test3   5385892905
2019-01-16 08:00:00.0   test1   4194204503
2019-01-15 08:00:00.0   test1   115598553821
2019-01-15 08:00:00.0   test2   59736397346
2019-01-15 08:00:00.0   test3   5508381147
2019-01-15 08:00:00.0   test4   39377518945
2019-01-15 08:00:00.0   test5   35371907528
2019-01-14 08:00:00.0   test1   115598553811
2019-01-14 08:00:00.0   test3   5408381147
2019-01-14 08:00:00.0   test4   346377518945
```

Expected output -

```
2019-01-15 08:00:00.0   test1   115598553821
2019-01-15 08:00:00.0   test2   59736397346
2019-01-15 08:00:00.0   test3   5508381147
2019-01-14 08:00:00.0   test4   346377518945
2019-01-15 08:00:00.0   test5   35371907528
```

When I tried to use it for driving column(3) and max value from desired column (4) it worked

```
awk '{if (a[$3] < $4) {a[$3]=$4}} END {PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc" ; for (i in a) {print i, a[i]}}' file1.txt
test1 115598553821
test2 59736397346
test3 5508381147
test4 346377518945
test5 35371907528
```

I tried below command to print entire row but didn't work -

```
awk '{if (a[$3] < $4) {a[$3]=$4;b[$0]=a[$3]}} END {PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc" ;for (i in b) {print i, b[i]}}' file1.txt
2019-01-15 08:00:00.0   test4   39377518945 39377518945
2019-01-15 08:00:00.0   test2   59736397346 59736397346
2019-01-15 08:00:00.0   test3   5508381147 5508381147
2019-01-16 08:00:00.0   test2   902006478 902006478
2019-01-14 08:00:00.0   test4   346377518945 346377518945
2019-01-15 08:00:00.0   test5   35371907528 35371907528
2019-01-15 08:00:00.0   test1   115598553821 115598553821
2019-01-16 08:00:00.0   test3   5385892905 5385892905
2019-01-16 08:00:00.0   test1   28848859233 28848859233
```

Comment: What is your actual expected output? Do you want the date column or not?

Comment: Expected Output should have date column like I mentioned above.

Comment: @VIPIN KUMAR, give it sometime and when you see few answers to your question then try to select any answer as correct one out of them, happy learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***1st Solution:*** Could you please try following.

```
awk '
{
  a[$3]=$NF>a[$3]?$NF:a[$3]
  b[$3,$NF]=$1 OFS $2
}
END{
  for(i in a){
    print b[i,a[i]],i,a[i]
  }
}'   Input_file
```

***2nd solution:*** Following will take care of that output sequence of $3(3rd field) will be same as per Input_file's 3rd field sequence.

```
awk '
!c[$3]++{
  d[++count]=$3
}
{
  a[$3]=$NF>a[$3]?$NF:a[$3]
  b[$3,$NF]=$1 OFS $2
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
   print b[d[i],a[d[i]]],d[i],a[d[i]]
  }
}'  Input_file
```

Explanation of above code:

```
awk '
!c[$3]++{                                ##Checking condition if array c with index $3 of current line is coming first time in array c if this is TRUE then assign it $3 as an index current line.
  d[++count]=$3                          ##Creating an aray d whose index as count variable value which will increment each time cursor comes here and assigning value of this array d to $3 here.
}                                        ##Closing block for array c here.
{                                        ##Starting block which will execute in all the lines for Input_file.
  a[$3]=$NF>a[$3]?$NF:a[$3]              ##Creating an array named a whose value is $NF of current line if value of $NF>a[$3] else it is NOT changing.
  b[$3,$NF]=$1 OFS $2                    ##Creating an array b whose index is $3,$NF and value will be $1 OFS $2.
}                                        ##Closing block here.
END{                                     ##Starting END block of awk program here.
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){                 ##Starting a for loop from i=1 to till value of count here.
   print b[d[i],a[d[i]]],d[i],a[d[i]]    ##Printing value of array b whose index is d[i], array a whose index is d[i] value AND value of d[i].
  }                                      ##Closing block for, for loop now.
}'  Input_file                           ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

---

---

***EDIT:*** Adding reason why OP's try is not working.

***OP's code:***

```
awk '{if (a[$3] < $4) {a[$3]=$4;b[$0]=a[$3]}} END {PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc" ;for (i in b) {print i, b[i]}}' file1.txt
```

***Explanation IMHO why code is not working:*** Since array b's values are NEVER getting deleted or changed(whenever a 3rd column's value is lesser or greater than its previous values) so that is the reason whe you are traversing through array `b` then it is printing all the values of array b. We need to change value of array b whenever value for 3rd field is lesser than its previous value.

Answer (score 1):

Try this please:

```
$ awk '!n[$3] || n[$3]<$4{n[$3]=$4;l[$3]=$0;}END{for(i in l) print l[i]}' file1.txt
2019-01-15 08:00:00.0   test1   115598553821
2019-01-15 08:00:00.0   test2   59736397346
2019-01-15 08:00:00.0   test3   5508381147
2019-01-14 08:00:00.0   test4   346377518945
2019-01-15 08:00:00.0   test5   35371907528
```

I moved the condition outside, for concise and for efficiency.
Also I changed the `key` to the value of `$3` where you are using entire line as key(`$0`).
Since you are trying to ouput the entire line, so they should be the value, and the values of column 3 should be the keys.

Answer (score 1):

Non-awk solution using the always handy [GNU datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/):

```
$ datamash -Wsf groupby 3 max 4 < example.txt | cut -f 1-4
2019-01-15  08:00:00.0  test1   115598553821
2019-01-15  08:00:00.0  test2   59736397346
2019-01-15  08:00:00.0  test3   5508381147
2019-01-14  08:00:00.0  test4   346377518945
2019-01-15  08:00:00.0  test5   35371907528
```

Answer (score 1):

with `sort/awk` cooperation

```
$ sort -k3,3 -k4nr file | awk '!a[$3]++'

2019-01-15 08:00:00.0   test1   115598553821
2019-01-15 08:00:00.0   test2   59736397346
2019-01-15 08:00:00.0   test3   5508381147
2019-01-14 08:00:00.0   test4   346377518945
2019-01-15 08:00:00.0   test5   35371907528
```

Answer (score 0):

I figure out the problem, I should have store the `$0` on driving column(3) for array b when desired condition met (find max value from `$NF` save into driving column(3) a[$3]=$4) not array a of column(3) into array b with entire line. something like this -

```
awk '{if (a[$3] < $4) {a[$3]=$4;b[$3]=$0}} END {PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc" ;for (i in b) {print b[i]}}' file1.txt
2019-01-15 08:00:00.0   test1   115598553821
2019-01-15 08:00:00.0   test2   59736397346
2019-01-15 08:00:00.0   test3   5508381147
2019-01-14 08:00:00.0   test4   346377518945
2019-01-15 08:00:00.0   test5   35371907528
```